# matlab - how to make 3D axes size go outside of figure

Tags: image, matlab, plot, figure, axes

I first created a figure with the background as a .png image. Then I created a 3D axes on top of the figure so that the 3D axes is placed on top of the .png image. Note that the .png image is not set inside of the 3D axes but is set outside of the axes in the figure itself.

I have a 3D .stl file of an apple set inside of the 3D axes (you can't see the apple by the way). When I move the apple around inside the 3D axes, using the option from the builtin Matlab figure toolbar, it works fine. But the problem here is that when I move the apple outside of the borders of the 3D axes, it disappears.

To tackle this problem, I want to set the size of the 3D axes so that its limits go outside of the figure, so that I can move my apple around anywhere in the figure without being limited to the size of the 3D axes. Note: I didn't make the 3D axes invisible, so that it is easier for people to understand my question. But when this problem is solved I will use `axis off` to make the 3D axes invisible, while retaining and displaying the apple.

[image]
**Here is the main code**

```
pearImage = 'pears.png';
appleModel = 'apple.stl';
backgroundImage = imread(pearImage);    
[vertices,faces,~] = stlRead(appleModel);

axesHandle = axes('unit','normalized','position',[0 0 1 1]);
imagesc(backgroundImage)
set(axesHandle,'handlevisibility','off','visible','off')
uistack(axesHandle,'bottom')

stlPlot(vertices,faces)
```

**Here is the function for `stlPlot()`**

```
function stlPlot(vertices,faces)

object.vertices = vertices;
object.faces = faces;
patch(object,'FaceColor',[0.1 1.0 1.0],'EdgeColor','none')
camlight('headlight')
material('dull')

axis('image')
view([-135 35])

axis off % used to make the 3D axes invisible
```

I got the `stlRead()` and `stlPlot()` functions from here: https://kr.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/22409-stl-file-reader?focused=5193625&tab=function. Note that I edited the `stlPlot()` function to fit my purpose.

Comment: Show a [mcve] so we can reproduce it

Comment: @AnderBiguri Hi, I have added the code so that users can reproduce it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you can solve this problem by changing the [`'Clipping'` property](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/patch-properties.html#property_d0e727284) of the [patch objects](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/patch.html) you create:

```
hPatch = patch(object, 'FaceColor', [0.1 1.0 1.0], 'EdgeColor', 'none', 'Clipping', 'off');
```

Or, more simply, you could probably just set the [`'Clipping'` property](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/axes-properties.html#property_d0e56058) of the parent [axes object](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/axes.html) itself (which controls clipping behavior for all of its children):

```
set(get(hPatch, 'Parent'), 'Clipping', 'off');
```